# Parse Querying the database in background Or Parse REST API which is better ?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using PARSE as backend for my android app so I want to know wether using REST API and parsing JSON data is better than querying the database in background ??.

> I want to know the advantages of one over the other ?
>
> In my case I would be using it to query a large amount of data to retrieve several post feed information (Heterogeneous) and am looking for a fast and efficient solution so which one would be better ??

Have found this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286788/what-is-faster-using-rest-api-or-querying-a-database-directly) which confused me a further.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't 100% sure, so I looked at the code and my assumptions were pretty much true.

Here are a few snippets of code from the Parse Android API.

When you went to save a file:

```
...
final ParseRESTFileCommand command1 = ParseRESTFileCommand.uploadFileCommand(fileName, ParseFile.this.data, mimeType, sessionToken);
command1.enableRetrying();
tcs.getTask().continueWith(new Continuation() {
    public Void then(Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
        if(task.isCancelled()) {
            command1.cancel();
        }

        return null;
    }
});
...
```

When you want to run cloud code:

```
public static <T> Task<T> callFunctionInBackground(final String name, final Map<String, ?> params) {
        return ParseUser.getCurrentSessionTokenAsync().onSuccessTask(new Continuation() {
            public Task<T> then(Task<String> task) throws Exception {
                String sessionToken = (String)task.getResult();
                ParseRESTCloudCommand command = ParseRESTCloudCommand.callFunctionCommand(name, params, sessionToken);
                return command.executeAsync().onSuccess(new Continuation() {
                    public T then(Task<Object> task) throws Exception {
                        Object result = ParseCloud.convertCloudResponse(task.getResult());
                        return result;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

In both cases, Parse is making REST API calls in the background for you. The big difference is that Parse has made it SO much easier to read by making an abstracted version of all the REST commands. And while I haven't profiled the actual speed differences to give you a quantifiable answer. I can assure you that choosing the pure REST API over the Android API for a minute (if existent) improvement is a prime example of [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Comment: You mean Parse Queries like query.findInBackground etc make use of REST API calls in background ? So shall I directly use REST services than querying the database in background ??

Comment: I don't think you get it. They are the same thing. Making direct REST calls is very ugly and hard to code. Parse made different platform APIs that makes it easy to read and understand different calls. If you are on Android, you should be following this(https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data) tutorial and this guide(https://parse.com/docs/android/guide).